# Error 5242 on LinqToSQL Execute Method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm getting the following error during code execution of a particular stored procedure and i'm stumped. Some other stored procedures work correctly but this one doesn't for some reason.

```
Warning: Fatal error 5242 occurred at Nov 25 2009 12:44PM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator


Line 66:        public ISingleResult<report_EventSummaryResult> EventSummary([Parameter(DbType="VarChar(7)")] string event_id, [Parameter(DbType="VarChar(12)")] string id)
Line 67:        {
Line 68:            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), event_id, id);
Line 69:            return ((ISingleResult<report_EventSummaryResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
Line 70:        }
```

Stack Trace

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Warning: Fatal error 5242 occurred at Nov 25 2009 12:44PM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1950890
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4846875
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2392
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CloseInternal(Boolean closeReader) +169
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Close() +96
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +292
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +954
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +141
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() +12
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +975
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +113
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +344
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters) +69
   MVCApp.Models.EventReport.EventReportDataContext.EventSummary(String event_id, String id) in C:\Documents and Settings\lalex\Desktop\MVCApp\MVCApp\Models\EventReport\EventReport.designer.cs:68
   MVCApp.Models.EventReport.EventReportRepository.GetEventSummaryResult(String event_id, String Event) in C:\Documents and Settings\lalex\Desktop\MVCApp\MVCApp\Models\EventReport\EventReportRepository.cs:20
   MVCApp.Controllers.EventReports.EventReportsController.Generate(FormCollection formCollection) in C:\Documents and Settings\lalex\Desktop\MVCApp\MVCApp\Controllers\EventReports\EventReportsController.cs:56
   lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +140
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +24
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__7() +52
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +254
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__9() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +192
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +399
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +126
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +151
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +7
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Has anyone ever encountered this error?
What does it mean and how can I correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326394.aspx

Sounds like you have a possibly corrupt, or damaged database.AFAIK, you're only likely to hit this problem with hardware issues, or more improbably, a bug in Sql Server.

Be careful following their instructions however, as DBCC CHECKDB (with one of the repair clauses) will delete data if it needs to, to get the DB into a normal state again.